# Matched status not writing in csv file

Tags: bash, shell

My `input.csv` file data look as below and so on.

| filename |
| --- |
| a.c |
| a.cpp |
| a.xml |
| abc.txt |
| abcd.json |

I have another `textfile.txt` file like below and so on

```
/data/reports/a.c
/data/reports/dir1/a.cpp
/data/reports/dir2/samples/b.java
/data/reports/dir3/yum/c.json
/data/reports/rate/abcd.json
/data/reports/d.xml
```

My `input.csv` need to check if the filename exists in my `textfile.txt` file or not, if existing it need to write in my `outputcsv` file's `B` column saying `existing` if not leave as empty. For this task i'm using below bash script.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read -r filename existing || [[ -n "$filename" ]]; do
  if grep -q "$filename" textfile.txt; then
    matched=$(grep "$filename" textfile.txt)
    echo "$filename,$existing,$matched" >> output.csv
  else
    echo "$filename,$existing," >> output.csv
  fi
done < input.csv
```

But above script not writing whether `existing` or not in my `output.csv` file's `B` column. So what could be the issue?

**Expected output:-**

| filename | status |
| --- | --- |
| a.c | existing |
| a.cpp | existing |
| a.xml |  |
| abc.txt |  |
| abcd.json | existing |

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: According to what you posted, `input.csv` has one "field" per line (the filename), but you are trying to read two values from each line (`filename` and `existing`).

Comment: Right. both my input files `input.csv` & `textfile.txt` has single column, My script need to check each file present in `input.csv` with `textfile.txt`. If file match found script to write in my `input.csv` file's corresponding row in `B` as existing if not it can leave blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F/ '
    NR==FNR{a[$NF]; next} 
    FNR==1{print "filename,status"} 
    FNR!=1 && !/^ *$/{printf "%s,%s\n", $0, ($0 in a) ? "existing" : ""}
' /tmp/textfile.txt /tmp/input.csv > output.csv

$ cat output.csv
filename,status
a.c,existing
a.cpp,existing
a.xml,
abc.txt,
abcd.json,existing
```